Debian Driver issues
I have recently built a PC. Specs:

Mobo: TUF GAMING B650-PLUS WIFI
GPU: Radeon Rx 6800 XT OC
CPU: Ryzen 7 7800x3d
RAM: 2x 16GB 6000Hz CL30

First I've installed Windows. That system had problems with using the mobo's network card. After installing the provided drivers it all came together nicely and works without issues.
Minor issues
Unfortunately, I've encountered many problems during Debian installation (I want to have both systems). During installation, the installer was unable to configure DHCP, so I simply skipped this step and continued without the internet connection.
After installation, I was unable to use wifi (I haven't checked if the RJ45 port works), so I'm using my phone to share internet through usb.
I might add that bluetooth also doesn't really work, it's unable to connect to any device and sometimes it doesn't even register surrounding devices.
I was unable to find proper drivers. There are only drivers for Red Hat, Ubuntu and SLED. I couldn't find any quick fixes, so I didn't bother with this issue (I won't be using the network adapter anyways).
The most important issue
is that my GPU refuses to output HDMI signal (now, my monitor is connected to the integrated graphics).
Let me clarify what happens if I connect my monitor through HDMI (I don't have display port in that device). My screen simply constantly displays:The image of the freezed screen. Changing the to the mobo's port after that freeze makes the screen work correctly. Changing back, to gpu reverts to the same freeze screen.
The text on the freezed screen:
Booting `Debian GNU/Linux'

Loading Linux 6.1.0-18-amd64 . . . 
Loading initial ramdisk . . .

I've tried running apt update, apt upgrade. Running sudo update-initramfs -u resulted in printing a lot of missing modules, which I've installed according to the fix provided here and here. The second fix actually was onto something, I didn't have the "firmware-linux" pacakge installed (I did install it). Yet after all this, after running sudo update-initramfs -u I get:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes.bin for module amdgpu

I'll be grateful for any help, because I'm unable to solve this issue by myself.
EDIT: After running the suggested commands my sources.list file looks like this:
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 12.5.0 _Bookworm_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20240210-11:28]/ bookworm contrib main non-free-firmware
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware


Edit 2: The system or someone, flagged this as a [duplicated] question. I assure you it was not, the fix in the linked question DIDN'T work for me. The problem was, that I had an old version of bios installed on my mobo. After updating bios the gpu problem vanished (I might add, that I've tried many things and in the end I've installed Ubuntu 22.04.04 instead of Debian 12). For the record, the version of bios my mobo was using was 1811, and the version that works for me is 2413. I've also had the newest (6.0.60002) amd drivers installed while I've updated my bios. I would have closed this question, if it hadn't been closed before, by someone who didn't assess the situation well or the system.
So yeah, kids update your bios if you've got such a strange driver issue.

You're missing the firmware for your AMD Radeon graphics card.
Because those are non-free binary blobs they aren't carried in the main branch of the distro, and for the latest version of Debian they split those off into a separate branch called non-free firmware to differentiate them from "regular" non-free software.
(Please don't ask; the discussions about this were long, tiresome, and repetitive and not pertinent)
Check your sources in /etc/apt/sources.list and check if you have the following lines:
(Given you're using kernel 6.1 I'm assuming you're on Debian 12, 'Bookworm')
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware

(If you want to have other non-DFSG-free software available as well, add contrib and non-free as categories after main )
This will include the non-free-firmware category for apt to pull in. After this, re-run apt update and then apt install firmware-amd-graphics which will download the firmware for your AMD graphics card.

I've tried what you have suggested, my /etc/apt/sources.list looks like this
"# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 12.5.0 Bookworm - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20240210-11:28]/ bookworm contrib main non-free-firmware
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware"
I've run sudo upgrade, sudo update and sudo apt install firmware-amd-graphics. But the firmware-amd-graphics was already installed on my system. The problem persists.

Please add the contents of your sources.list to your original question; comments don't handle formatting.

I've edited my original question
